# is it possible for JWT to generate a same token, two times?

Tags: jwt

is it safe to only use tokens to access/change a user's data in database?
Imagine I get a request with only jwt inside of it and I want to change something for only that user using his token which is stored in database, How do I be certain that no two users have same tokens stored in database? Do I need to get his username ( another data stored in database ) and compare both of them or only token is enough?

Comment: I did google and found that jwt won't generate a token twice, but I just want to get certain

Comment: "his token which is stored in database" - one of the main purposes of JWT is that you don't need to lookup in the db. Just verify by signature and exp.

Comment: @jps this really helped, removed JWT from db entirely, THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably<sup>tm</sup>. The chances of users details hashing to the same string (a collision) are pretty darn small.

The header will be quite common but the payload will vary wildy, depending on the algorithm. The signature is a product of the first two so a collision depends on the payload. This has so info on that (see the accepted answer) https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-many-rsa-keys-before-a-collision

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answers is that it is possible but it's very very unlikely that this will happen